# How to store ArrayList element into Array in Java?

Tags: java

I am new to Java and was wondering if anyone would help me out with the logic below. What am trying to do is to iterate over a list and store each list element into Array. Once that's done, then I want to check the array element for correct answers. So for example 3,2,1 is enter then the final score should be 3. Here is the code.

### Code

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class IterateOverArray {

public static int SCORE = 0;
static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
static int[] temp;
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    list.clear();
    list.add(3);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(1);
    getScore();
}

public static void getScore() throws RemoteException {

    temp = new int[3];

    for (Integer value : list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            temp[i] += value.intValue();
        }
        if (temp[0] == 3) {
            SCORE++;
        }
        if (temp[1] == 2) {
            SCORE++;
        }
        if (temp[2] == 1) {
            SCORE++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("total score: " + SCORE); // Final Score should be 3!
}
}
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking exactly; e.g. *...for correct answers...* - what does it mean: *correct*?

Comment: Am basically trying to work on question and answer assignment. The user answer three question and the answers are 3,2,1. Then I put a check with the if statement; if answer 1 at index[0] = 3, then we increment the score + 1, if answer 2 at index[1] == 2, then again increment score by etc and print score at the end.<br> Remember answers are coming from the list.add(3)<br>list.add(2) etc!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just put the correct answers in an array, and compare them as you go. No need to transform things into arrays and whatnot.

```
int getScore(List<Integer> answers) {
    Integer[] correctAnswers = {3,2,1};
    int score = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        if (correnctAnswers[i].equals(answers.get(i)))
            score++;
    return score;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt with an algorithm: **Mental Step-through!**

1. call `getScore()`
2. new array `tmp`, all elements initialized to `0`
3. first iteration, value of `value` is `3`
4. add `3` to all elements in the array (makes **all** of them 3)
5. check if first element in array is `3` --> it is, increase Score
6. next iteration, value of `value` is now `2`
7. **add** `2` to all Elements of the array (makes **all** of them `5`)
8. ...

You see your flaw here?

The values in `tmp` will grow higher, and will then never evaluate to `true` in your `if`-statements. Did you want to use `=` instead of `+=` in your inner for-loop?

---

Here is a sample-implementation:

```
static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// ...
list.add(3);
list.add(2);
list.add(1);
getScore();

public static void getScore() throws RemoteException {
    if (list.get(0) == 3) {
        SCORE++;
    }
    if (list.get(1) == 2) {
        SCORE++;
    }
    if (list.get(2) == 1) {
        SCORE++;
    }
    System.out.println("total score: " + SCORE);
}
```

A `List` is just a *dynamically growing* array. It behaves just like an array and you can get a single item from it by using the `get(index)`-method (which is the "equivalent" to using `[index]`).

You don't need to copy your contents, at all. But if you must use an array, you can convert a `List` to an array by using the [`List.toArray()`-method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29).

Comment: I want the final score to be 3! please read the comment above for what I want to achieve.

Comment: @Learner I know, and this is your problem. After the second iteration, the values in your `temp`-array are **all** `5`.

Comment: how do i make it to print 3 not 5?

Comment: @Learner I guess what you're trying to do is copy the contents of the `List` into an array and then check if the right answer-number was set at the right question-index?

Answer (score 0):

```
package farzi;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListToArray 
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrList.add("hussi1");
        arrList.add("hussi2");
        arrList.add("hussi3");
        String[] strArray = new String[arrList.size()];
        arrList.toArray(strArray);
        for(int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(strArray[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How is this answering my question? Please explain your ans?